# Flutter doctor says flutter plugins not installed even though I have

Tags: flutter

C:\Users\Vostro\AndroidStudioProjects\covid_tracker>flutter doctor -v
Error: PowerShell executable not found.
Either pwsh.exe or PowerShell.exe must be in your PATH.
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.22.2 at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision 84f3d28555 (5 days ago), 2020-10-15 16:26:19 -0700
• Engine revision b8752bbfff
• Dart version 2.10.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Vostro\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Vostro\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more
details.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[!] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\Vostro\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
X Flutter extension not installed; install from
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.

Comment: Make sure you follow the guidelines while asking a question

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue related to Flutter version 1.22.2. You can upgrade your Flutter version to the beta channel or you can do the following step as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986#issuecomment-707508419):

```
  flutter config --android-studio-dir=<path/to/installation>
```